# Realms in Asterisk

Tags: linux, voip, asterisk

How can a system (Asterisk) accept realms? I mean, for example we have two SIP accounts: `exampleuser@test.com` and `exampleuser@anothertest.com`. For Asterisk by default, these two accounts are the same since the user is `exampleuser` for the system. I want the domain to be  also included in the username, so for example to accept only users with a certain domain.

How can this be achieved? Guides or books referring to this topic are well accepted :) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set it up like:

```
...
domain=test.com
domain=anothertest.com
domainsasrealm=yes              ; Use domains list as realms
; You can serve multiple Realms specifying several
; 'domain=...' directives (see below). 
; In this case Realm will be based on request 'From'/'To' header
; and should match one of domain names.
; Otherwise default 'realm=...' will be used.
```

Regards

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure for the `realm=...`, I wanted a confirm, the option to have multiple realms is just what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one guide : [Configuring and Using SIP Domains in Asterisk](http://www.smartvox.co.uk/astfaq_sip_domains.htm).

Please try everything that looks pertinent and comment on it in your post, so we can know what you did or did not